# Automapper; mapping a string[] to Dictionary<MyEnum, string>

Tags: automapper

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
class Source
{
   int MyProperty1 { get; set;}
   ....
   string[] MyStrings { get; set;}
}

class Destination
{
  int MyProperty1 { get; set;}
  ...
  IDictionary<MyEnum, string> MyStrings {get;set;}
}
```

Here is the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

Mapper.CreateMap<string[], IDictionary<MyEnum, string().
       ConvertUsing<CustomArraytoDict>();
```

And the ITypeConverter implementation:

```
public class CustomArraytoDict : ITypeConverter<string[], IDictionary<MyEnum, string>>
{
    public IDictionary<MyEnum, string> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var periodNames = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>();

        //Create new Key Value pairs from 
        //context.SourceValue and add them to periodNames.

        return periodNames;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that "ConvertUsing()" should ensure that during mapping AutoMapper should use the reference for MyStrings dictionary as provided by CustomArraytoDict. However I do not see that happening. AutoMapper does seem to call correctly CustomArraytoDict during mappping of Source object to Destination object but the MyStrings reference in the Destination object remains the one created and initialized by the Destination constructor. The reference returned by CustomArraytoDict is not used.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Automapper are you using?  I just tried this scenario using AM 2.0 and it worked fine.  Can you post a complete, failing unit test?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? Thanks